# Google Play App Update Not Visible

Tags: android, google-play

I have updated my application in Google Play Store, and it is visible in Developer Console that application is updated, but it is showing old version in Google Play.

Can any one tell me what could be the issue . It has be more than 48 hours application got updated.

Answer (score 0):

**first recheck your versionNumber and versionCode is same as previous version, It should be greater than previous one, if it was correct you can contact googleplay-developer-support@google.com they will suppory you. good luck..**

Comment: versionNumber and VersionCode is different then previous version, and yes only option left is to contact support

Answer (score 0):

1st - make sure in your build.gradle (app) file you always increment the version code. Under android{defaultConfig {...}}.

2nd - upload your newly built APK to Google play. And then if it's under alpha release remove the testers or discontinue the previous uploaded version.

3rd - I downloaded the play console app, which informs you that your update is being processed ... (I would add an image but apparently my reputation isn't high enough)

Finally make sure you always use the same key to generate your signed APK. And also don't change your applicationId which is found in your build.gradle file. (Just above the versionCode mentioned before)

Hope this helps others who find this later on.